# Add-MpPreference is not working on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, security, windows-defender

first I'm a Windows user. I'm going to exclude my files with the 'Add-MpPreference' command. I'm excluding my files because I don't want Windows Defender deleting my files because my files are threatening this laptop, so I want to stop Windows Defender is deleting these files. So, I'm using the 'Add-MpPreference' command(I run this command on Powershell Administrator). But it didn't WORK! And I also found people had this problem in StackOverflow. They said the solution is to use PowerShell 64-bit, not 32-bit. I'm confused, I already use PowerShell 64-bit, not 32-bit. And to make sure I'm using the 64-bit PowerShell, I'm using this command

[image]

See? I'm using 64-bit Powershell. When I want to exclude my files with the 'Add-MpPreference' command, the output is annoying:

[image]

The important thing is, this command cannot work, and most StackOverflow users aren't learning Ethical Hacking. Probably, someone helps me?? I've done what I can do

Comment: 0x800106ba usually means Defender is disabled because another AV product is installed ...